# Is it possible to involve a search bar on a DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, pyqt5

I have a DataFrame in Pandas which collects some data from an Excel document. I created a GUI with PyQt5 in order to make it look more interesting but here is the thing.

Is it possbile to make a dynamic search bar in order to search through that DataFrame? For example, my DataFrame has over 3k+ rows and I wanna search for John Doe, then the results will come up on the GUI. As far as I know, QLineEdit is used for this but I can't seem to implement it on my code.

Is it me that is doing wrong or it is not possible to do it on a DataFrame? And if anyone wanna help me, just let me know, I would be so grateful and thankful, I guess it'll only take 10-15 minutes. I can also post the code here, but talking on Discord and explaining you in detail and also sharing screens would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by subclassing `QAbstractTableModel` to create a custom table model that uses the underlying dataframe for supplying data to a `QTableView`. This custom model can then be combined with a `QProxyFilterSortModel` to filter the data in the table. To create a custom non-editable model from `QAbstractTableModel` you need to implement `rowCount`, `columnCount`, `data`, and `headerData` at the very least. In this case, minimal implemetation could be something like this:

```
class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data_frame, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data_frame = data_frame

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return 0
        return self.data_frame.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return 0
        return self.data_frame.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return str(self.data_frame.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return self.data_frame.index[section]
        else:
            return self.data_frame.columns[section]
```

To show and filter the data in a table you could do something like this:

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        # by default, the QSortFilterProxyModel will search for keys in the first column only
        # setting QSortFilterProxyModel.filterKeyColumn to -1 will match values in all columns
        self.proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.proxy_model)

        # line edit for entering (part of) the key that should be searched for
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.filter_text)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.table_view)

    def filter_text(self, text):
        self.proxy_model.setFilterFixedString(text)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.model = DataFrameModel(pd.DataFrame(data))
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWidget()
    win.set_data({'a':['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':['green', 'yellow', 'red']})
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Of course this is a very basic implementation but I might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think the library [pandas_ui](https://github.com/arunnbaba/pandas_ui) is what you are looking for here.

It allows you to play with your dataframe interactively, i.e. in a microsoft excel fashion. Particularly, the column filtering option should do what you want.